# 'Beware of' or just 'beware?'

Tags: word-usage

> Beware of the man who agrees with all that you say: *he wants your job!*
>
> BEWARE the man who agrees...
>
> Beware the flashy car and the fashionable wife, *the penurious misogynist said.*
>
> BEWARE OF the flashy car and the fashionable wife...

I know this question has been asked before here

> [Beware vs. beware of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353080/beware-vs-beware-of)

but OP apparently did not find a conclusive answer, and after reading the whole discussion I am still not quite certain when or where to use 'beware of' and when to go with just 'beware.' Can somebody provide a 'rule of thumb' for this usage?

Comment: Regardless of proper usage, "Beware the man who agrees" isn't nearly as frequently used in colloquial speech (at least in the US) as "Beware of".

Comment: Little known fact: Caesar would still be alive today if "of" hadn't been left out of "Beware of the Ides of March".

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the intriguing information; and I just love your statement 'Caesar would still be alive *today* (if...)' which, maybe unintentionally, reminds us: don't forget to have fun with the language! The word-picture of a still-alive, 2044-something-year-old Julio Cesar is not just admirable, but positively adorable for those who love language and its mysterious quirks!

Comment: @GrammaRay thank you; somebody did suggest that 'beware' without 'of' is more used by writers and dramatists, apparently to achieve a poetic or classical effect as in 'beware the cup of gold, O King, that it turn not into a poisoned chalice, methinks!'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beware vs. beware of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353080/beware-vs-beware-of)

Comment: If a question has been asked before, but not sufficiently answered, the "accepted" behaviour is to post a bounty on that question rather than ask a new one, as the new one should just be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: This occurred because I was new to the site at the time and unaware of the duplicate rule, nor understood I must check for possible earlier duplicates before posting my question @AndyT.

Comment: @EnglishStudent - Yeah, I looked at the date and figured that may have been the case. But as I came across this question (not sure how... maybe from the "Related" box) I thought I'd do some tidying up of the site.

Comment: Correction: reading the question again I see I have clearly identified it as a duplicate myself but felt that the earlier answer is not conclusive. So you are very right about what we are expected to do in that situation, but I didn't know it and nobody pointed it out at the time, thanks @AndyT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that both arrangements are acceptable modern grammar, however there are nuances that could affect the intent of the writer.

The word “beware” is a Middle English portmanteau or contraction of “be” and “aware”. Adding the predicate “of” indicates *what* should be of concern for this solicitation of awareness (e.g., “Beware ***of*** Greeks bearing gifts”).

When used as a single word, it becomes a call to action or command, as in “Beware: Dog”, as well as the simple exclamation, “Beware!”

In the sentence, “Beware *the* man who agrees with all that you say...”, the predicate is *implied,* however it may not be technically accurate to drop it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is "Beware of". The origin of the word "beware" comes from the middle English term "be ware". ware is a word that could mean merchandise or to be watchful, curious, or wary. and saying "be wary of" is the proper use of the word. "be wary of that man" not "be wary that man" as far as i know.

Comment: 'Be wary of' is a good way to deconstruct the usage!